# Should I provide two "Then" in Cucumber in this scenario?

Tags: testing, cucumber, case

I am writing test cases in Cucumber and I have been wondering is this type of scenario ok to provide two then's.

I have a situation where after user does something in the app, let's say makes an order, the success notification is shown. Is it ok if I make a test case like this:

```
Given the user has downloaded the app
And logged in to the app
And user has item in basket
When user clicks "Buy"
Then order is created
And success notification is displayed
```

Or should there be two separate test cases: one for order being created and one for success notification being displayed after order has been created?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no set rule as to the number of consequences a single action can have. In fact, I could argue that a single action will have multiple expected results more times than not. For example, when you authenticate into a web site, you may want to validate the contents of the landing or home page. Since the page will most likely have multiple components present, you may have to check each and every one. In that case, your scenario

```
Given the user has downloaded the app
And logged in to the app
And user has item in basket
When user clicks "Buy"
Then order is created
And success notification is displayed
```

seems totally reasonable. In contrast, creating two separate scenarios is not reasonable. Why? Assuming the above scenario takes 10 seconds to complete, checking the conditions for the `Then` and the `And` will take twice as long because you have to repeat all the previous step, just to get to the expected outcome. This is true for this case, and this case alone. There might be cases when separating expected results into separate scenarios might make sense. This specific one is not one of those.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @kkk please consider upvoting my answer if it was helpful, and selecting it as the answer by clicking the checkmark by the answer if I truly answered your question satisfactorily.